# 403 forbidden occurs for some URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, http-status-code-403

I want to know how to remove 403 issue for particular URL .
For example ,whatever comes after http://www.example.com/webapp/* , I need to remove 403 issue. How to set this?

Answer (score 0):

you must configure your web server to allow pages from that file directory to be served to the public. 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#user